# Data Entry Form Refreshes into Old Record

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form with a subform (subform is linked to an ID on the main form). I want the subform to only be a data entry form (I have already set the following settings: Data Entry = Yes | Allow Additions = Yes | Allow Deletions = No | Allow Edits = Yes). When I load the main form, the subform shows a blank form, which is what I want. My subform also has a 'New Record' button to create a new blank record for data entry. This button works fine.

The problem I encounter is when I click 'Refresh All' (on the Access menu ribbon), the first record of the subform pops up. One workaround that I've tried is to lock that entire subform once the user clicks outside of the subform. That works fine as well, however the user now encounters a problem where they haven't finished data entry, click outside of the subform, are locked out, and are now unable to edit the record they were working on.

Is there any way to stop that first record from showing up (ie: make my subform only show blank fields at all times)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subform to be data entry only don't link or bound it. Just use unbound controls and then VBA to validate your data and create the record.

There are ways to do this with a linked and bound form but the disadvantages of doing it this way far outweigh any advantages.

Comment: When you say that the subform shouldn't be bound/linked, are you referring to the record source? Or that the subform shouldn't be linked to the mainform?

Comment: Also, I don't have much experience with unbound data entry forms, do you have any preferred resources that you use?

Comment: If the sub-form is not bound then it can't be linked. I don't have any specific resource. I have been using Access for a very long time so these things are pretty basic to me. An unbound form does not write its data directly to any Access tables. It is up to you to script the various events like data updates and button clicks in VBA to create new records.

Comment: I see, ok great thank you very much. I will give it a try